# How to resize iframe on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, resize, window

I am trying to resize the iframe element on window resize like this:

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L34am/)

the only difference is that in my original code I have pdf document as src but not the apple website.

```
src='link-to-local-pdf'
```

I want it on window resize to make it respectively resize the iframe itself and not to add scroll on the window but only on the iframe. Can you help?

Comment: So you want the iframe to take up as much space as possible without adding scrollbars?

Answer (score 2):

Hoping I understood what you are after correctly.
Here is an example of a page where the iframe makes itself always just fit inside its parent window.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/My6mj/

javascript:

```
// set initial size
$( document ).ready(SetIframeSize);

// resize on window resize
$(window).on('resize', SetIframeSize);

function SetIframeSize(){
    $("#external").width($(window).width() - 18); // added margin for scrollbars
    $("#external").height($(window).height() - 35);
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <br/>
    <div id="iframe-wrapper" align="center" style="z-index: 0">
        <iframe id="external" src="http://www.apple.com/">dada</iframe>
    </div>   
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work without JavaScript:

1. Calculate the aspect ratio of the iframe content (height/width).
2. Wrap the iframe in a div.
3. Apply styles to the wrapper:

   .wrap {
   position: relative;
   padding-top: /* aspect ratio in % */
   overflow: hidden;
   }
4. Remove width and height from the iframe.
5. Apply styles to the iframe:

   iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
   }

Answer (score -1):

This is doing, what you want.

```
<body>
   <iframe id="the_iframe"></iframe>
</body>

#the_iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

The trick is the absolute positioning, which is practically *relative* to its parent. This css gives the the_iframe practically an 50px margin, but in the whole body window.

Comment: Did you actually try it? Because I just tried it but it is nothing different of what I had before. It keeps on adding scrolls to the window.

Comment: I am sorry - I am glad to say to you, how can it be done, I am glad to explain to you, how it works, but I won't debug your script, if you didn't even try to understand, what I explained you.

Comment: Well, I don't want you to debug my script. I have added link to jsfiddle where I have given an example which is pretty basic and explainst what i am aiming. I just need to make the iframe autoresizable somehow. I don't need the window scrolls.

Comment: okay try it yourself here http://jsfiddle.net/L34am/7/ . How could you claim that it works when it is obvious that it does not. I don't want you to do my work

Comment: Ok I check this, plz wait a little

Comment: I checked this, this is a problem of the jsfiddle. In a real site it worked.