# Adjusting the layout of the contents of an iframe depending on the window size

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, python-sphinx

I have an iframe that links to a Fortran code documentation created using [FORD](https://github.com/Fortran-FOSS-Programmers/ford). It has the same layout as [this](https://jacobwilliams.github.io/json-fortran/) page. I want to use an iframe on my sphinx website to display its contents on one of its pages. However, linking to it causes the layout of the iframe contents not to change as it would if only the documentation was opened. Instead, it pushes the full-sized window to the left so that only half of it is visible, like in the following picture:

[image: current full website layout]

Is there a way to scale the iframe contents down as the window layout changes so that the borders are first minimized, and then a scrollbar is displayed at the bottom? The iframe is embedded into the site as follows:

```
.. raw:: html

      <iframe src="path_to_FORD_documentation_index.html" style="position:fixed; top:auto; left:auto; bottom:auto; right:auto; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:auto; padding:auto; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
      Your browser doesn't support iframes
      </iframe>
```

I have already tried the javascript-based approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568997/how-to-resize-iframe-on-window-resize/54488530) question, but this only created a scrolling bar at the bottom of the main page but didn't resize the iframe's contents.

Comment: "I have already tried the approach..."  - What approach? The linked question has three answers,

Comment: @mzjn added the missing info

Answer (score 0):

Without having much to go on, I think your problem is in your `height` and `width` properties. Your DOM is loading the iFrame before the iFrame is loading the content. So when the element is created, it's got no width or height to it, so the iFrame defaults to min height/width. Solution could be to preload the iFrame link:

`<link rel="preload" href="https://path_to_FORD_documentation_index.html" as="document">`
then call iFrame as you do now

OR you could resize the iFrame in a function and call it after the page loads:

```
<script>
iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth
iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
</script>
```

Comment: I tried both of your approaches and didn't see anything changing. I also tried manually setting the height to 200px,  but the size of the iframe content is still scaled in a way that would fit a fully expanded regular window

Comment: where is your iFrame nested in the DOM?

Comment: it's nested inside of two divs

Comment: could you add more of the HTML so we can get a better picture of what styles might be affecting it? something in one of the parent divs could be affecting it